# Mongodb Node.js : socket.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I have developed a chat application with socket.io with mongodb but still I have a doubt Could I use socket.io with mongodb to build a consultant forum website. 
**If not then why?**

Comment: socket.io doesn't have anything to do with mongodb, your question doesn't really make sense. Of course you can use mongodb.

Comment: sir I am using mongodb driver const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient; mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongochat', function(err, db){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }}

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:PORT/DATABASE', (err) => {
  if(err){
    console.log("error" + err);
  } else{
    console.log("mongodb connected");
  }
})
```

It must be done. Mongoose is a good library to connect MongoDB with Node.js.